# Как в запросе обрезать данные при получении сравнении?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что делаю фильтры на сайте, по городу, месяцу и дню.

Для города я сделал приравнивание WHERE `city` = $_GET['city']

Вот сам запрос:

```
$cat_result = mysqli_query( "SELECT * FROM `poster` WHERE `cat` = '".$cat_q['id']."' AND `city` = '".$_GET['city']."'");
```

Не могу сделать такой же фильтр для месяца и дня, потому что эти данные хранятся в одном столбце формата datetime и имеет вид 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Вот допустим дата 2017-09-21 19:00:00 месяц этой даты 09.Мне его нужно = к $_GET['month'] (Сам монтх = 09) то есть если я буду приравнивать запрос в таком виде

```
$cat_result = mysqli_query( "SELECT * FROM `poster` WHERE `cat` = '".$cat_q['id']."' AND `date` = '".$_GET['month']."'");
```

не будет работать ибо будет такое 2017-09-21 19:00:00 = 09

А мне нужно сразу в запросе выбрать лишь месяц.

Надеюсь, что разложил всё по полочкам :)

Заранее спасибо !

Comment: + используйте PDO либо фильтруйте параметры. в данном варианте возможен sql injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант. Давно с MySQL не работал — не знаю будет или нет эффективно работать.

```sql
SELECT
    p.id
  , p.city
FROM
  poster p
WHERE
  YEAR(p.date)      = 2017
  AND MONTH(p.date) = 9
;
```

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT * FROM `poster` WHERE `cat` = '".$cat_q['id']."' AND DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%m') = '".$_GET['month']."'"